# Error while wrapping a component in a graphql query

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I'm using an Apollo client to send request to a GraphQL server.

So I wrapped a react component in a GraphQL function in this way

```
GraphQL(query)(HomeView);
```

An I got this error:

> Argument of [object Object] passed to parser was not a valid GraphQL
> DocumentNode. You may need to use 'graphql-tag' or another method to
> convert your operation into a document

How may I resolve this issue?

Here is my component code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const query = {
    query: gql`
        {
            hello
        }
    `
};

class HomeView extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Home</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default graphql(query)(HomeView);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap all the query in gql tag:

```
const query = gql`
    {
      hello
    }
`;
```